# Why can I still do addition with a subtraction magic method?

Tags: python, magic-methods

This isn't as much of a problem as it is a genuine question coming from a place of ignorance of how Python works under the veil.

I saw a bit on magic methods and decided to try writing some code with them to check out how exactly they were supposed to work and, through the trials and errors in which I did things wrong on purpose, I found that this code actually works:

```
class Vector:
  def __init__(self):
    self.n1 = 1

  def __sub__(self, n):
    return self.n1 + n

x = Vector()
print(x - 3)
```

Thing is, the code returns to me the value 4 - which means it is adding the two numbers instead of either telling me it can't solve this because I wrote the wrong sign or giving me a negative number as a result

At the same time, if I write the code like this:

```
class Vector:
  def __init__(self):
    self.n1 = 1

  def __sub__(self, n):
    return self.n1 + n

x = Vector()
print(x + 3)
```

... it automatically ceases working and says I'm doing something wrong (well, obviously, I'm trying to do addition in a subtraction method! It's not *supposed* to work!)

I was wondering why exactly Python even allowed my first slip-up to begin with. What is happening behind the veil for it to actually run?

Comment: In the first example, `n`  in `def __sub__(self, n)` is `3`, the number to be subtracted, not `-3`.

Comment: Your `__sub__()` method actually does add the numbers, so 4 is the correct answer.

Comment: If you write a `__sub__` such that it adds, then sure it will add, you wrote it that way after all. What's the surprise?

Comment: @harold, the OP was probably anticipating that `n` would be `-3` in the first block of code.

Comment: Note that you've redefined what `-` means, so in the first example, when you `print(x - 3)`  your arguments aren't `x` and `-3`, they're `x` and `3`, with the `-` being the `__sub__` operation: as you're executing `__sub__` with `self.n1=1` and `n=3` , the code returns `self.n1 + n = 1 + 3 = 4`.

Comment: The whole purpose of defining the `__sub__` method, is to define what the `-` operator will do on objects of your class. You can define it whatever way you like...

Comment: *which means it is adding the two numbers* -- Right, because that is exactly what you told it to do.  You told it that the expression `a-b` when `a` is a `Vector` instance should result in `a.n1 + b`.

Comment: Put another way, the statement `print(x - 3)` is exactly the same as `print(x.__sub__(3))`, or even `Vector.__sub__(x,3)`.

Comment: It may be easier to understand if you view these dunder methods more as "triggered by an operator" than "strictly locked to an operation". In your case "-" is just triggering the `__sub__` method. What you tell that method to do is entirely your decision.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking at it wrong.

It turns out that Python is not very judgmental. Do you wanna add something in a method usually reserved for subtractions? So be it. Wanna print something instead? Aight. Wanna erase your hard drive? Up to you...

The **only** thing that Python is going to do when you write `some_instance - blah`, is calling the [dunder](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/magic-methods-in-python) method `__sub__` of `some_instance` (because of the `-`), with `some_instance` as the first parameter (`self`) and `blah` as the second. What that method does is up to you. Do you wanna add (as you do in your example)? Surefinewhynot?. Would you rather `print`? Fine:

```
class Vector:
  def __sub__(self, n):
    print(f"Hello {n}")

x = Vector()
x - "folks"
```

will show:

> Hello folks

As for your second question: Python doesn't know how to add an instance of `Vector` and the integer `3`. Is not because you are doing addition on a subtraction method. The subtraction method (`__sub__`) is not called at all. It doesn't matter whether it's there or not. Is because you're trying to add two things that can't be added (or rather: two things that Python doesn't know how to add).

```
class Vector:
  pass

x = Vector()
x + 3
```

The error is quite telling

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Vector' and 'int'

If you want to be able to add a `Vector` and an integer, you can always implement the dunder method `__add__` in `Vector`, of course

Oh, and don't let the name `Vector` of your class fool you, though. Just because the class is called `Vector`, it doesn't mean it's going to behave like one.

```
class Somethingy:
  def __sub__(self, n):
    print(f"Hello {n}")

x = Somethingy()
x - "folks"
```

Comment: Note that the actual confusion is about why `x-3` is 4, and that the OP expected that to either still subtract values, or fail. due to them misunderstanding operator overloading.

Comment: Yup, ( @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ) I'm aware. That's why I specifically mentioned **as you do in your example** in my answer. I mean... I tried to be as clear as possible... No? Let me know, though.

Comment: Thank you for putting what happened into words! I'm still a first year and already trying to explore OOP, so you can guess how confusing it can get sometimes. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't care about what you do in a function, that's the whole point of letting you define the operators. the first time you defined __sub__ which is called when you do x - y and you decided to do addition when __sub__ is called. The second time around you still defined __sub__ but not __add__, so python can't call __add__ when you do x + y